# "Send them my regards"

Tags: word-usage, conversation

If I want to tell to my friend to send "hi" to someone else, is it acceptable in the spoken English to say:

> "Send them (or him) my regards"

?

Answer (score 2):

> Send them my regards

Would work in this context, but is more commonly used to signify you are giving someone your respect, or gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is OK but rather formal.

Informally, I would say:

> Tell him (or them) I said "Hi". (or Hello)